# When importing stl models for 3d printing the pieces are all scattered, Is there a way to re assemble everything?

Tags: 3d-printing, units

[image]

This is the result of the imported model. Is the software? Or it comes this way and there is no other solution than manually fixing? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there is no other solution than manually fixing it.

It looks like a 3d printing model, and the parts are designed to be printed separately then assembled (it even look like an articulated model). Maybe try to contact the author, they probably have an "assembled" version of the file.